# Portable Mono Compiler

Tags: c#, mono, package, portability

Is there any way(or idea) to create a portable package(for Ex. mono C# compiler and runtime) on (For Example) All Ubuntu versions (and avoid download many packages for every system we need to work on)?

Comment: Are you mean the compiller only or also you need a portable mono runtime to launch applications?

Comment: Write it in C#, it is portable.  You'll know when you get close to being done when your compiler can compile itself.  Or find out there wasn't any point to it.

Comment: yes.Of course we need mono runtime to launch the app.

Comment: Do you know that to run mono applications without mono runtime you may use mkbundle utility?

Comment: mkbundle with static linking should help.

Comment: mkbundle makes bundle of a compiled code and binary files.Is it possible to bundle the compiler with mkbundle?

Comment: You may try to write a compiller application based on Mono.CSharp.dll (lates version avaliable from nuget) and then mkbundle it. Not sure that this might work.

Comment: That's a nice idea...also a hard one! Is there any app like that which I can start from?

Comment: Yes. CS-Script(http://www.csscript.net/) for example but I think it isn't use mono.charp.dll. Also CSharp Repl (can't find link to source) which is a part of mono runtime if I'm not mistaken and it built on mono.charp.dll and I think this is what you need. Moreover popular game engine Unity3d uses mono.csharp.dll. Also you may find a lot of other examples.

Comment: And here is a very simple example http://blog.davidebbo.com/2012/02/quick-fun-with-monos-csharp-compiler-as.html